# Is it possible to filter a List with a function that returns Future?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list `List<Item> list` and a function `Future<bool> myFilter(Item)`.

Is there a way to filter my `list` using the Future returning function `myFilter()`?

The idea is to be able to do something like this:

```dart
final result = list.where((item) => myFilter(item)).toList();
```

But this is not possible since `where` expects `bool` and not `Future<bool>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the iteration involves async operation, you need to use a `Future` to perform the iteration.

```
final result = <Item>[];
await Future.forEach(list, (Item item) async {
  if (await myFilter(item)) {
    result.add(item);
  }
});
```

Comment: I hope dart will implement `asyncWhere` for `Stream` class soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your collection and asynchronously map your value to the nullable version of itself. In `asyncMap` method of `Stream` class you can call async methods and get an unwrapped `Future` value downstream.

```
final filteredList = await Stream.fromIterable(list).asyncMap((item) async {
      if (await myFilter(item)) {
        return item;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }).where((item) => item != null).toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow:

1, Convert List => Stream:

example:

```
Stream.fromIterable([12, 23, 45, 40])
```

2, Create Future List with this function

```
  Future<List<int>> whereAsync(Stream<int> stream) async {
    List<int> results = [];
    await for (var data in stream) {
      bool valid = await myFilter(data);
      if (valid) {
        results.add(data);
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution to create a **whereAsync()** extension function using ideas from the accepted answer above. No need to convert to streams.

```
extension IterableExtension<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Future<Iterable<E>> whereAsync(Future<bool> Function(E element) test) async {
    final result = <E>[];
    await Future.forEach(this, (E item) async {
      if (await test(item)) {
        result.add(item);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

You can now use it in fluent-style on any iterable type. (Assume the function **validate()** is an async function defined elsewhere):

```
final validItems = await [1, 2, 3]
  .map((i) => 'Test $i')
  .whereAsync((s) async => await validate(s));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
    final result = turnOffTime.map((item) {
      if(myFilter(item)) {
        return item;
      }
    }).toList();
```